# Make [segfault] a synonym of [segmentation-fault]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

I can't propose this tag synonym directly, but I've noticed that [segfault](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/segfault) should be a synonym of [segmentation-fault](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault).  Can someone make this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a good synonym to me.

Tag synonym is now created and merged, with [segmentation-fault](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault) as the master on the grounds of quantity.